# List of Inherited Objects in Another Inherited Object

Tags: c#, inheritance, uwp, abstract

I have five models:

1. An abstract `Album` model.
2. An abstract `Artist` model.
3. An `AlbumTypeOne` model which inherits from `Album`.
4. An `ArtistTypeOne` model which inherits from `Artist`.
5. An `ArtistTypeTwo` model which inherits from `Artist`.

My `Album` model will have a list of `Artists` on it. However, I don't know whether the artists will be `ArtistTypeOne` or `ArtistTypeTwo`, and I don't care. So I added this to my `Album` model:

```
public abstract List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
```

But when I try to override this property for JSON deserialization in `AlbumTypeOne`:

```
[JsonProperty("artists")]
public override List<ArtistTypeOne> Artists { get; set; }
```

it doesn't like that.

From what I understand of inheritance and abstract classes, this should work. Is there a different way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify which subclass of `Artist` an album class must use then you could do this:

```
public abstract class Album<TArtist> where TArtist : Artist
{
    public List<TArtist> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

`where TArtist : Artist` indicates that the generic type of `TArtist` must be `Artist` or something that inherits from it.

Then `AlbumTypeOne` can be declared as

```
public class AlbumTypeOne : Album<ArtistTypeOne>
```

The `Artists` property doesn't need to be abstract and you don't need to override it. Inheriting from `Album<ArtistTypeOne>` specifies what the generic argument is. The `Artists` list will only accept `ArtistTypeOne` (or something that inherits from `ArtistTypeOne`.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you expose too much of the data in `Album`. Instead of making the list public, there should only be abstract methods for iterating through `Artist`s, adding one and removing one (basically repeating the relevant parts of the `List` interface). Each derived class implements these access methods, returning actual `ArtistTypeOne`  or `...Two` from a private or protected data structure.

Admittedly this solution is less type safe than Scott's suggestion: What should you do if somebody tries to add an `ArtistTypeTwo`  to an `Album` which is actually an `AlbumTypeOne`? (Possibly throw an exception.)

Or you provide only getters for the base `Artist`  and strongly typed `Add` methods for each derived `Album` type, because in the context of adding an artist you must know the precise `Album` type (while in the context of iterating through an `Album`s artists, e.g. in order to print a list of tracks, the specific type of `Artist` is irrelevant -- they all have `ToString()` etc.).